# python oracle gets result into dictionary and matches the given list

Tags: python, oracle, dictionary, python-2.6

[image: SQL Results]

How can I match the given list from the sql result into dictionary?
Here is my code:

```
import cx_Oracle

con = cx_Oracle.connect('fmstech','fmstech','fmsdev')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("select * from num_prefix where network = 'GLOBE'")

globe = ['639988800000', '639066256904', '0150422 153023']
results = {}
for lines in cur:
    results[lines[0]]=lines[1]
    globe1 = globe[1][2:5]
    if globe1 in results:
        print '906 is exist'
    else:
        print '906 is not exist'

cur.close()
con.close()
```

but I got the result:`906 is not exist`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is this. use `int()`

```
globe1 = int(globe[1][2:5])
```

**Example 1:** **with out int()**

```
results = {817: 'globe', 906: 'globe'}
globe = ['639988800000', '639066256904', '0150422 153023']
globe1 = globe[1][2:5]
if globe1 in results:
        print '906 is exist'
else:
        print '906 is not exist'
```

o/p

```
906 is not exist
```

**Example 2 : with int()**

```
results = {817: 'globe', 906: 'globe'}
globe = ['639988800000', '639066256904', '0150422 153023']
globe1 = int(globe[1][2:5])
if globe1 in results:
        print '906 is exist'
else:
        print '906 is not exist'
```

o/p

```
906 is exist
```

**Reason :**

In dict the key is number here but where as globel is string in your code. So convert it as NUMBER and compare.